# Is this a correct translation for “Today I read a book”

Tags: traducción

Hoy he leído un libro.

I think this is it, but any corrections would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Hoy he leído un libro` is one correct translation.  Literally, that is "Today I have read a book," although that form is used more in Spanish than in English.  You could also say `Hoy leí un libro`.